# Is the space elevator supposed to be based on any real concept?

Tags: special-effects, the-wandering-earth-2

In the initial segment of the movie *The Wandering Earth 2*, a space elevator plays a central role.

**Are there any known statements by the production staff behind the movie (making-of notes etc.) that explain to what extent the depicted elevator is meant to be based on real-world concepts? Or was the depiction merely an instance of the rule of cool?**

Background for the question: I am quite familiar with the hypothetical idea of a space elevator, but in the variants I have read about, the advantage over rockets or similar vehicles has always been described as avoiding the necessity of carrying the additional weight of boosters and the fuel for them along with the payload.

The space elevator shown in the movie, in contrast, seems to strongly rely on rockets built into each lift capsule, until some kind of grappler pulls the capsule up along the final portion of the tether.

---

*Note that I'm aware that ultimately, that movie is mainly a nonsensical action flick that just tries to pour in as many special effects and explosions as possible to gloss over the lack of plot logic. However, it plays just a couple of decades in the future and some of the depicted technology is reminiscent of realistic concepts - e.g. the moom rovers or the vertical take-off plane -, so I'm trying to find out whether the space elevator is meant to be among the somewhat realistic parts of the movie.*

Comment: [Skyhook.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyhook_(structure))

Comment: @JRE - maybe, though I'd have thought a Skyhook to become effective at quite a bit lower an altitude; the movie makes ot seem like only the very last short part of the distance to the space station would be covered without the rocket engines.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper If it's a rotating skyhook, raising the altitude of a payload is only a secondary point; the primary point is boosting the payload to orbital velocity.  And the connection point is always going to be _at least_ 100km altitude for a rotating skyhook (higher for a non-rotating one) in order to minimize drag.

Comment: @DavidW: I see; not sure whether rotating drag was much of a concern in the movie's design, as the elevator tethers reached all the way down to the ground (and somehow also held various annular structures along the way in place).